# I can't install views module. Error Memory or infinite loop

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I avoid the error “out of memory”?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4293/how-do-i-avoid-the-error-out-of-memory)

In my site, I can't install Views module. When I check it on admin/modules and then I press on save configuration I've got these error:

> **Fatal error**: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in (...)/public_html/includes/menu.inc on
>   line 3714.

This is the code of menu.inc file:

```
3709  $item += array(
3711    'access arguments' => array(),
3712    'access callback' => '',
3713    'page arguments' => array(),
3714    'page callback' => '',
3715    'delivery callback' => '',
3716    'title arguments' => array(),
3717    'title callback' => 't',
3718    'theme arguments' => array(),
3719    'theme callback' => '',
3720    'description' => '',
3721    'position' => '',
3722    'context' => 0,
3723    'tab_parent' => '',
3724    'tab_root' => $path,
3725    'path' => $path,
3726    'file' => '',
3727    'file path' => '',
3728    'include file' => '',
3729  );
```

Problem with `'page callback' => '',` ??

It's like a infinite loop that crash, because 256 M for Drupal 7 it would be sufficient.

Actually the value of variable `memory_limit` of php.ini is 256M . I can't increase it because is a shared hosting, and 256M is the limit. I don't have access via SSH

I try to modificated this value in settings.php, but it's locked on 256 by hosting provider

`php_info` show this:

```
Directive        Local Value    Master Value
memory_limit     256M           256M
```

The list of installed non-core modules are:

- Administration menu
- Boost
- Chaos tools
- Libraries
- Pathauto
- Pathologic
- Redirect
- Smiley
- Sub-pathauto
- Tagadelic
- TagCanvas
- Token
- Transliteration
- XML sitemap

Thank for you reading. Grettings

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem if there is 256M ram allocated. What i would suggest is clear your cache and install one module at a time. Like rather then installing the whole views list of module just install one by one. Another good option is to use drush to install modules but unfortunately you do not have ssh access.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply @j2r. I try to clean all cache and install Views module, but falls again. The list of modules that are installed are non-core. Not that the install at a time. The only module that I try to install, it is the views module. **I Edited the post with menu.inc code**